# Generate symmetric key in openssl

Tags: openssl, aes

I need to generate 128 bit symmetric key according to AES standard in openSSL. Unfortunately I can't find one in openssl. How to generate symmetric key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53668354/2908599) as reference. The command is:

```
openssl rand -hex 16
```